# Android: How to change dynamically size of child views to fit parent view size?

Tags: android, layout, view, children

I have a LinearLayout with 3 or 4 views (Buttons and ImageButtons) inside, and I want that all of them have the same size to fit entirely the layout, like shown in the picture below [image: example]
 The same thing must be done either in horizontal and in vertical.

the xml of the LinearLayout is this:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/discover_right_action_bar"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/top_navi_bar"
    android:background="@color/smart_dark_grey"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/home_ib_friend"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:saveEnabled="false"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_select_all" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/home_ib_camera"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:saveEnabled="false"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_camera" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ib_prof_mon_meetings"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:saveEnabled="false"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/clock" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now I can only set or the size manually in dp, or set it to wrap_content, but than there would be space at the beginning and at the end of the layout.

I've tried something with the layout_weight attribute but I don't know well how to use it.

I've tried also with getting the real size of the layout (via ViewTreeObserver) and set the size to the internal children but it doesn't work because I couldn't get the real dimension of the layout.

Comment: How much views are there in your layout? is it 3 or 4? You can do it simply using weight sum and layout_weight. How you tried it? If not i can give you a example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve my problem: the solution above is working but I remove the weightSum attribute and it works if you don't know how many child views will be there. Their size will be adjusted dinamically and automatically to fit the whole parent layout.

Answer (score 3):

if its vertical

```
 <LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/discover_right_action_bar"
android:layout_width="64dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:weightSum="3"
android:layout_below="@id/top_navi_bar"
android:background="@color/smart_dark_grey"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:paddingTop="5dp" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/home_ib_friend"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:saveEnabled="false"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_select_all" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/home_ib_camera"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:saveEnabled="false"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_camera" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ib_prof_mon_meetings"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:saveEnabled="false"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/clock" />
```

if horizontal:

```
 <LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/discover_right_action_bar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="64dp"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:weightSum="3"
android:layout_below="@id/top_navi_bar"
android:background="@color/smart_dark_grey"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:paddingTop="5dp" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/home_ib_friend"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:saveEnabled="false"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_select_all" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/home_ib_camera"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:saveEnabled="false"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_camera" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ib_prof_mon_meetings"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:saveEnabled="false"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/clock" />
```

Comment: Yes right. This was same i was going to suggest. Please accept the answer if this is helpful.

Comment: ah, so you use weight in every child view, I'll try tomorrow morning and if it's right I'll surely accept the answer, thanks!

Comment: Ok, I tested it and it's working perfectly when I know how many views there are in the layout.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know if there would be 3 or 4 buttons inside, because one is set with visibility GONE and at runtime it can become visibile.. If it's possible to set the weightsum at runtime it would be perfect, now I try to do it.

However thank you, I accepted your answer.